# Use of Phrasal Verb 'Yearn for'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I'd like to ask if the following sentence is grammatically correct: 
**It is a rare luxury yearned for by even those who have it all.**

I am especially concerned with the usage of the phrasal verb "yearned for" - should it be "yearned" instead? If neither of these two constructions are correct, can you suggest another verb that will make the sentence more effective? I am thinking of using "sought" instead, although I don't think that it communicates the level of intensity that 'yearning' does.

Thank you!

Comment: Yearned for even by those...

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, the sentence is grammatical. It definitely should not be "yearned" -- if you use yearn, you need for. But if you prefer a single word there are alternatives: craved, coveted, desired...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comment by @Marv, reordering 'even' and 'by' scans better, and it would probably be 'sought after' as a replacement for 'yearned for':

> > It is a rare luxury sought after even by those who have it all

Comment: Why is *sought after* any better than *yearned for*?

Comment: No better, just the question mentioned use of 'sought', sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep it simple:
It is a rare luxury fancied *even* by those who have it all.